# TypeScript: Get Type of Super Class?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I was wondering if there was a way to get the type of extended class in typescript.

```
class BaseClass {
    baseProp: string;
}

class SubClass extends BaseClass {
    subProp: string;
}

type someType<T> = T extends infer U ? U : T;

type superType = someType<SubClass>; // want this to be BaseClass
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think so.  The type `SubClass` is equivalent to `{ baseProp: string, subProp: string }` in the structural type system.  That type has no pointer to `BaseClass` inside it.  If you need this behavior you'll need to manually keep track of class parent types, possibly by systematically adding a phantom property to each class in your hierarchy pointing to the immediate parent.

Comment: @jcalz Hmmmm, what I was essentially looking for is to get the props of a class excluding all the props of the super class, could we do that in a principled way?

Comment: You can do `Pick<SubClass, Exclude<keyof SubClass, keyof BaseClass>>`, but deriving `BaseClass` from `SubClass` doesn't seem possible.  If you are in control of the class hierarchy you should consider defining these diff types *first* and then having your classes implement them, so you have a name for them and you'll get an error if you forget any of them.

Comment: Well on of the issues I've had with respect to implementing types, is it will not flag an error in case optional properties are not implemented.

Comment: Because optional properties are optional.  If you want an error, make the property required.  I don't like writing too much code in comments, so if you have some specific example you should make a question for it or edit this one (although "optional properties" seem to have nothing to do with this question as stated)

Comment: Well defining the diff type first I feel is the best option. Thanks anyway. God bless.