# Get type of properties unique to a child class

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to construct a TypeScript type that extracts the property names that are unique to a specific class, that it did *not* inherit from its parent class? For instance, this works if I know the parent class ([Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=48&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKYCcCmA7ALtA3gWAFDQOgAskQQB7aAXmgHISzza8BfPPUSGAYSIEsQAE2hIAHmlSCY8ZOix5C0AO7kEQ6nRVrBzXG1x40ATwAOSaAHklKWAnImIAHgBCkJABpoAFRHjJMVwgkAD4NAFFRUABXQSRHAGskI3IAM29PROS0wJD2XFjOZGhgchQIDHJrW3sIAC5LKrsHRxlUNE9eAUFgoA)):

```js
class Parent {
    hello = 'hello'
}

class Child extends Parent {
    world = 'world'
}

type OwnProps<Base, T extends Base> = Exclude<keyof T, keyof Base>

declare const ownProps: OwnProps<Parent, Child> // "world"
```

However, I would like a way to accomplish the same type of thing, but without explicitly specifying the base class, something like this:

```js
type OwnProps<T, Base = T extends ???> = Exclude<keyof T, keyof Base>

declare const ownProps: OwnProps<Child> // "world"
```

Is this possible? Is there some kind of conditional magic I can use in place of `???` that would let me `infer` types that the `Child` class extends?

Comment: If you have a constant number of base classes, you might be able to cheat and do something possibly fragile and wrong through conditional types, such as for each base class, you check whether the subclass is a strict superset of the base, and if so, select that base class.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it looks impossible. TypeScript uses [structural type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system) and a type doesn't store any information about class hierarchy, i.e. the `Child` type it's just `{ hello: string, world: string }`.

You can also look at the other similar question: [TypeScript: Get Type of Super Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56377792/4858777)

Comment: This may not help, but just noting that _sometimes_ classes are nominal in TypeScript: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#when-and-why-are-classes-nominal